# javascript/jquery simple search engine - implement a simple search engine, data stored in an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, frontend, search-engine

**Question is Edited!** I have stored all products name in an **Array** in **object format**. I have a input[type=text], too. I need a simple code to search among this array.
SQL command is like : **(SELECT name FROM tbl_product WHERE name LIKE %txt% )**. But I am implementing this on frond-end and there is no connection to back-end!

```
<input type="text" id="mytxt" />

<script>
// [{ in_ordered_id : "product name"}, ...]
var products_name = [{ 8 : "product ninety two"}, {21 : "product two"}, {35 : "product nine"} , ....];
$("#mytxt").keyup(function(){
     var txt = $("#mytxt").val();
     var results = start_search(txt); // `results` must be array of ids e.g. [35, 98]

});

function start_search(text){
     /// I don't know what to write here
}
</script>
```

Comment: A case-insensitive regex? Levenstein distance? What's the actual issue? What have you researched already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string.includes` might help

```js
products_name = ["product one", "product two"];


$("#mytxt").keyup(function() {
  var txt = $("#mytxt").val();
  var results = start_search(txt);
  console.log(results);
});

function start_search(text) {
  return products_name.filter(pr => pr.includes(text))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="mytxt">
```

--Edit

```js
const products_name = [{
  8: "product ninety two"
}, {
  21: "product two"
}, {
  35: "product nine"
}]


$("#mytxt").keyup(function() {
  var txt = $("#mytxt").val();
  var results = start_search(txt);
  console.log(results);
});

function start_search(text) {
  return products_name.filter(pr => Object.values(pr)[0].includes(text)).map(pr => Number(Object.keys(pr)[0]))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="mytxt">
```

Comment: tnx... this really helped me :)

Comment: Updated answer. Please make question next time

Answer (score 0):

How about using the array.indexOf function?

```
products_name = ["product one", "product two"];

function start_search(text){
     if(products_name.indexOf(text) > -1){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
};

start_search('product'); // returns false
start_search('product one'); // returns true
start_search('product two'); // returns true
start_search('product three'); // returns false
```